# Jenkins pipeline - getting a security error, how can I prevent the error from being raised?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing an Android build prcoess in Jenkins pipeline as a code.
The relevant portion of the script is:

```
def notifyStarted() {
  // send to Slack
  slackSend (channel: '#slack-test', color: 'warning', message: "STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]' (${env.BUILD_URL})")
}
def get_current_time_date() {
    Date date = new Date();   // given date
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
    calendar.setTime(date);   // assigns calendar to given date
    TIMEH = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // gets hour in 24h format
    TIMEM = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    TIMES = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    newdate = date.format( 'yyyy-MM-dd' );
    def result = newdate + '%' + TIMEH + ':' + TIMEM + ':' + TIMES
    result
}
// Mixpanel parameters

// End of Mixpanel parameters

node ('master') {
    notifyStarted()
    sh '( git reset --hard; git clean -fxd; git tag -d $(git tag) ) &>/dev/null || true'
    checkout scm
    MP_VERSION_NAME = sh '(git tag | grep '^[0-9]' | tail -n 1)'
    MP_API_KEY = "cXXXXXXXXXf"
    MP_API_SECRET = "4XXXXXXXXX4"
    MP_EXPIRE = "1588896000"
    MP_APP_PLATFORM = "Android"
    MP_BASE_URL = "http://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/annotations/create?"
    //RELEASE_DATE =  get_current_time_date()
    MP_RELEASE_NOTES = ""
    DESCRIPTION = "${MP_APP_PLATFORM}%v${MP_VERSION_NAME}${MP_RELEASE_NOTES}"
    REQUEST_URL = "api_key=${MP_API_KEY}&date=${RELEASE_DATE}&description=${DESCRIPTION}&expire=${MP_EXPIRE}"
    REQUEST_URL_NO_AMPERSAND = REQUEST_URL.replaceAll('&','')
    REQUEST_URL_API_SECRET = "${REQUEST_URL_NO_AMPERSAND}${MP_API_SECRET}"
    SIGNATURE = "md5 -q -s ${REQUEST_URL_API_SECRET}".execute().text
    CURL_COMMAND = "${MP_BASE_URL}${REQUEST_URL}&sig=${SIGNATURE}".replaceAll(' ','%20')
    def cwd = pwd()
    stage ('Compilation environement preparation') {
        // Build parameters
        NDK_VER="r12b"
        SDK_VER="r24.4.1"
        GRADLE_USER_HOME="${cwd}/.gradle"
        NDK_DIR="${GRADLE_USER_HOME}/android-ndk-${NDK_VER}"
        SDK_DIR="${GRADLE_USER_HOME}/android-sdk-linux"
        SDK_TOOLS="${SDK_DIR}/tools"
        AAPT="${SDK_DIR}/build-tools/23.0.3"
```

When running the build, I get the following error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified method java.lang.String xor java.util.ArrayList
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:30)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:48)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor243.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor244.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:50)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor243.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:324)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:78)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:236)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:224)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I believe the issue has something to do with the get_current_time_date function but I'm not sure how.

I've read about the error on the internet and found that I can go to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> In-process Script Approval and approve certain code runs but how can I prevent this from happening? I'm not sure which code (out of 3) or which signature (out of 3) are the ones I should approve and in any case I want the pipeline to be able to run automatically, without human intervention.

Any idea what causes this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentionned, you need to manually approve some methods signatures by doing it in `Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> In-process Script Approval`. It is a security system that sandboxes Groovy code execution so you don't execute dangerous/malicious code. You can't really avoid it, however you will need to approve **each signature just once**, not at every run.

In short, approve manually the signatures until you have treated them all, and then you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, and how serious is the threat of approving code which Jenkins regards as security vulnerability?

Comment: I guess it depends on a lot of things, e.g. which signature you are approving and which users you allow to create new pipelines. So it can range from "no threat at all" to "risky" :)

Comment: It's possible for Groovy code to be executed, rejected, and not appear under `In-process Script Approval`.  `java.lang.SecurityException: Rejecting unsandboxed method call: WorkflowScript.invokeMethod(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;)`

Answer (score 0):

Move your logic/code to a global shared library code and it will be trusted automatically (you must be a jenkins admin).

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#global-shared-libraries

"These libraries are considered "trusted:" they can run any methods in Java, Groovy, Jenkins internal APIs, Jenkins plugins, or third-party libraries. This allows you to define libraries which encapsulate individually unsafe APIs in a higher-level wrapper safe for use from any Pipeline"

Comment: I'm getting the kind of problem exactly with a shared library