# Jenkins pipeline groovy odd behavior

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a groovy pipeline script:

```
stage("Test") {
    str="[\"asd1\", \"asd2\"]"
    def tagNames = str.tokenize(',[]').collect { it as String }
    echo "${tagNames.getClass()}"
    echo "${tagNames.size}"
}
```

But on the output I see error "No such field found: field java.lang.String size":

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] echo
class java.util.ArrayList
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
No such field found: field java.lang.String size. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I have "No pending signature approvals."

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129455/jenkins-pipeline-getting-a-security-error-how-can-i-prevent-the-error-from-be

Comment: I see ""No pending signature approvals."

Comment: This happened to me when my Jenkinsfile had a bunch of invisible characters like `<U+200B>`, which I could find only using `git diff`. Happened due to copy-paste from https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using

```
size()
```

instead of

```
size
```

does the trick.